# how to remove even indexes from Array list untill the list becomes empty?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

i am facing this problem from the long time please somebody wil help me.
I want to remove all the even Index number.

Input = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

output should be 1) 1,3,5,7,8,9

2) 1,5,7,9

3)1,7,9

4)1,7

```
   import java.util.*;
   public class Puzz1 {
       public static void main(String...sdf) {
         ArrayList <Integer> pep = new 
         Array<Integer> ();     
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        pep.add(i);

    int size = pep.size();
    while (size > 0 ) {
        for (Iterator <Integer> iterator = pep.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Integer number = iterator.next();
                if( number % 2 == 0 )
                    iterator.remove();      
        }//for loop
        size = pep.size();


        System.out.println(pep.toString());
        System.out.println(pep.size());
    }//while
   }
 }
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: What do you want to remove? Even elements (like the title says) or even index numbers (like the question body says)? Also way can a block of three successive numbers (7, 8 and 9) survive the first round? Shouldn't at least one of them be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we can remove the elements present on `even` indices from the list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));

while(list.size() != 1) {
    int index = 1;
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        if(index++ % 2 == 0) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List after removal : " + list);
}

System.out.println(list);
```

It prints the list after every pass. However, I am not sure how your solution ended with `8` in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Note: since the array index starts from 0, after removing even indexes from `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` the output will be `2,4,6,8,10`. To achieve that you can remove elements from the end of array and using recursion continue removing until the list becomes empty:

```
public void removeEven(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    removeEven(list);
}
```

In case to get only odd numbers like `1,3,5,7,9` use `i % 2 == 1` instead 
Also be careful with `8` in your output example. I'm not sure why is it there

Answer (score 0):

The below code will remove the even indexed numbers from the list:

```
public void removeEvenIndex(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++) {
          if (i % 2 == 0) {
              list.remove(i);
          }
      }
      System.out.println(list);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, you want to remove the elements located at ***even indices***. iterating through the arraylist ***from the last to the first element*** and checking each index if it is even and removing the element at that specific index will do the trick. the main thing here is ***iterating in reverse order*** because iterating from index 0 to the end doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Thanks for taking the time to clearly explain the principles at work here.  However to answer the question, you'd really need some code (as other answers have).  As it stands, this is a commentary posted as an answer, which is discouraged.